# ASP.NET Core Identity - NormalizedUserName, NormalizedEmail

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

While developing a multi-tenant app with ASP.NET Core I noticed that it brings 2 new indices: `NormalizedUserName` & `NormalizedEmail`.

The main problem is that it gets too difficult to have **a unique user per tenant**.

What I mean is having multiple users with the same **UserName** & **Email** but different **TenantID**.

In order to achieve this I have to remove those indices

```
public static void RemoveIndexes(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
    {
        var normalizedUserNameIndex = entity.HasIndex(u => new { u.NormalizedUserName }).Metadata;
        entity.Metadata.RemoveIndex(normalizedUserNameIndex.Properties);

        var normalizedEmailIndex = entity.HasIndex(u => new { u.NormalizedEmail }).Metadata;
        entity.Metadata.RemoveIndex(normalizedEmailIndex.Properties);
    });
}
```

---

**My questions are:**

- What is the purpose of these 2 new indices?
- What would it affect if we just remove them?
- Is there anything we need to pay close attention to after removing them? (e.g. overriding default `UserManager` functionality or something to that effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't change anything of the Identity Framework if I can't oversee the effects. If you insist, you can test what happens yourself. But, do you need to remove the fields?

If the relation of *user-to-tenant* is *one-to-many*, then tenantId should not be a field of ApplicationUser but rather be stored in a seperate table, like *UserClaims*.

You can add multiple tenantId's as claim of the same type, like http://tenant.company.com/Id. It will then become a collection of values, like what happens with roles.

If you don't want this then you can use different claimtypes, like http://tenant.company1.com/Id, http://tenant.company2.com/Id or something like that.

You can choose to include only claims that are linked to the tenant, which could be determined from the site binding or the url, for instance.

This design allows the user to login using the same password everywhere. Please note, this is about identity: *who is the user?* The user doesn't need to have a different password for every tenant.

It also makes it easier to change a password. Because I wonder, how does your scenario look like with multiple user records for each tenant? Will you update all records at once when a password changes? And how will you support 'forgot password' and other features?

Comment: In a multi-tenant application, users do not belong to more than 1 tenant. TenantA can have a user with the same username as TenantB. They are different accounts with different roles etc...